# Key-value to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I got a key-value object like this:

```
items = {1:"a",2:"v",3:"u"};
```

But i want it like this.

```
items = [{"key":"1","value","a"},{"key":"2","value","v"},{"key":"3","value","u"}];
```

What is the best way to do this?

I have already tried to do this with `$.each`.

```
var items = {1:"a",2:"v",3:"u"};
var newItems = [];
$(items).each(function(k,v){
    newItems.push({"key":k,"value":v});
});
```

And please tell me what is wrong with this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
 var items = {1:"a",2:"v",3:"u"};
    var obj=[];
    for(var i in items){
    obj.push({"key":i,"value":items[i]});
    }
    console.log(obj)
```